# How to create a custom filter in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I use alfresco enterprise 6.0. I want to create a custom facet filter based on a custom aspect. I have created a custom model which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model name="tm:contentModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

<imports>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
    <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
    <!-- Import Alfresco System Model Definitions -->
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys"/>
</imports>

<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://www.test.com/model/mymodel/1.0" prefix="tm"/>
</namespaces>

<aspects>        
    <aspect name="tm:myvaluea">
        <title>Test Property</title>
        <properties>
            <property name="tm:myvalueb">
                <title>Test Property</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
                <index enabled="true">
                  <atomic>true</atomic>
                  <tokenised>false</tokenised>
                </index>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </aspect>          
</aspects>
</model>
```

Following this documentation https://docs.alfresco.com/6.0/tasks/filtered-search-custom.html I have created `solr-facets-config-custom.properties` file which has the following content.

```
#Test
custom.tm\:myvalueb.filterID=filter_test
custom.tm\:myvalueb.displayName=Test
custom.tm\:myvalueb.displayControl=alfresco/search/FacetFilters
custom.tm\:myvalueb.maxFilters=3
custom.tm\:myvalueb.hitThreshold=1
custom.tm\:myvalueb.minFilterValueLength=2
custom.tm\:myvalueb.sortBy=DESCENDING
custom.tm\:myvalueb.scope=ALL
custom.tm\:myvalueb.scopedSites=
custom.tm\:myvalueb.isEnabled=true
```

In faceted search `filter by` column it displays as in the screenshot below. I have `undefined` in front of the property value. Not sure why the `undefined` shows up. Do I have to do any other configuration or customization to get this custom filter working?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a search facet on a text field, why not do it with the Search Manager? That way you don't have to worry about config files and you can set it up, test it, and tweak it without a restart.